# Mac OS X App fails to execute completion handler in release build but works in debug build

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I know this is rather vague but does anyone have any pointers as to why a completion handler does not get run in the release build but does run in the debug build.

I have not idea where to begin trying to solve this other than changing the code to not use a completion handler.

Any pointers would be welcome.

App is written in Swift and built for OS X 10.10

UPDATE
I just modified the code to send a NSNotification rather than run the completion handler and now things work fine.  I still have the completion handler code in but its not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't read minds. Can't help you if you don't show us the real code.

**BUT**. It it possible that you've come across a compiler bug. I've had a similar problem, where the Swift compiler would generate incorrect code in optimized (Release) build — but the same thing would work fine in Debug. (rdar://18906781) I've also heard of other production apps written in Swift that simply do not work correctly in optimized builds (and so are shipped unoptimized).

Try reworking the code to achieve the same thing with different code — maybe you'll work around the bug.

If you have the time, I encourage you to try narrowing the bug as much as possible to make a test case and reporting it on http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: I just has a simple `{ NSLog("completion handler running...") }` to eliminate the possibility that more complicated code was causing the problem and this does not get executed.  All the other code does get executed just nothing in `completion()`.  I think it must be a bug in the optimiser and will see if I can recreate the problem in a sample app.

Comment: BTW I did try turning off optimisation for the release build and it still failed to work!